# SOAP web service with spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, soap

I work with jhipster version 5 and I use java 8 and spring boot version 2 and postgres as a database and maven version 3.

I want to make an integration with other system which uses Oracle as a database.

I want to use  two function in oracle

```
insert into myView values (..........)
select firstName,Lastname,gender,....... from myView
```

in the oracle databse I have only view (  not a table )

the solution is to use soap webservice

so work with two project ( the first one use postgres and the second is soap project using oracle )

I want to know what better technology I need to use for the soap project

( soap with spring or with spring boot ....)

Comment: So are you asking what the difference between spring and spring boot is?

Comment: I want to choose between spring boot and spring for soap web service project based on  security,speed...